# Relating buttons outside form with form in accessible way

Tags: html, vue.js, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I have following simple html from Vue component

```
<div v-if="!answer">
   <h5>Question?</h5>
   <button>Yes</button>
   <button>No</button>
</div>
<form v-if="answer == 'no'">
  <label for="id123">Question 2</label>
  <textarea id="id123"></textarea>
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
<div v-if="answer='submitted'">
  Errors or success message from server
</div>
```

If the answer is "yes", it will be send to server.
If the answer to question is "no" there will be rendered textarea instead and then form will be submitted and send to server along with answer.
And then in both cases, after response from server, there will be rendered div with error or success message.

My question is, how can I relate buttons "yes" and "no with form? So screen readers and other assistive technologies know that is related to form with textarea? Using some aria-* attributes?

Or maybe I should structure html in other way?

Comment: Why don't you add the question and the yes/no buttons in the form ?

Answer (score 0):

`aria-controls` is supposed to make an association between one GUI element and another (e.g. a hide/show link associated with hidden/shown content).

[Support is quite poor and unpredictable](https://heydonworks.com/article/aria-controls-is-poop/), but strictly according to the spec, it's the right thing. However, I'm wondering why you don't just put the buttons in the form, since one of the buttons causes a form submission, and the other simply reveals more of the form.

BTW, consider using `<output>` for the server responses, because assistive tech will treat that as a live region, and announce it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this seems like a great use case for a simple `<input type="checkbox"`. Using a checkbox would allow you to track a Yes/No, True/False answer in a way that is accessible to the screen reader and easy to work with in your component and its submission.

If your UI must have a Yes and No button that set a value within the form, I would probably restructure the HTML to have a hidden checkbox input within the form whose value is set by whichever button is clicked.

Something like:

```
<div v-if="!answer">
   <h5 id="exampleQuestion">Question?</h5>
   <button
      id="yesButton"
      aria-describedby="exampleQuestion"
      v-on:click="myHiddenCheckbox = true">
      Yes
   </button>
   <button
      id="yesButton"
      aria-describedby="exampleQuestion"
      v-on:click="myHiddenCheckbox = false">
      No
   </button>
</div>
<form v-if="answer == 'no'">
  <label for="id123">Question 2</label>
  <input
    id="hiddenCheckbox"
    type="checkbox"
    aria-hidden="true"
    style="display: none;"
    v-model="myHiddenCheckbox">
  </input>
  <textarea
    id="id123"
    v-if="!myHiddenCheckbox">
  </textarea>
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
<div v-if="answer='submitted'">
  Errors or success message from server
</div>
```

In this example, `aria-describedby` would associate the buttons to the question they're meant to answer, although there are definitely better patterns available for gathering a Yes/No input as I described above. This wouldn't be an ideal usage of `aria-describedby` but I'm unsure of a better way to handle this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute